# Gist like on Github for Bitbucket

Tags: bitbucket, gist

I'm search some like as http://www.gistboxapp.com for http://www.bitbucket.com. Exist anything like that?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

<s>For Bitbucket, unfortunately, the current answer is NO.</s>

There is also an issue ([Issue #516](https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issue/516/repo-backed-pastebin-gists-bb-672)) report about this on Bitbucket issue trakers. You may follow its status there.

---

**Updated:** As of Mar. 19, 2015, Bitbucket has made this feature [available](https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issue/516/repo-backed-pastebin-gists-bb-672#comment-16566846), check out **https://bitbucket.org/snippets**.

Comment: The [issue #516](https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issue/516/repo-backed-pastebin-gists-bb-672) is marked as resolved as there is now snippets available (see @limonte's answer).

Comment: @emileb Updated the answer to incorporate this. Thanks.

Comment: It's 2017 and I don't see this "snippets" thing on our own install of BitBucket.

Comment: Anyone know if Bitbucket Snippets can be "secret" like Github Gists? "secret" means it is public if you have the exact URL, but otherwise not indexed/searchable.

Comment: as @trejkaz suggests I don't think this is available on bitbucket server which is a local\onprem install of bitbucket. In general a lot of features don't make there way down which is strange since we pay for the thing. There is a non free 3rd party plugin I guess.

Comment: There is a plugin, but it sort of leads to further disappointment. Gists on GitHub are stored in Git, so you get versioning. Once you edit a snippet in Bitbucket, you lose the old version permanently. The only workaround as far as I can see is to "Clone" every time.

Comment: @Trejkaz No, all old versions are saved in the `Revisions` page.

Comment: I see no link to such page. At least, not on the snippet page itself.

Comment: I should add, the lack of Fork is disappointing too. I frequently use that on GitHub to take a copy of someone else's useful gist for potentially modifying later.

Comment: @Trejkaz You can check out [here](https://bitbucket.org/snippets/herohuyongtao/6e8pba/revisions/) for an example.

Comment: That's public Bitbucket though. The version they trick you into buying to install on your own server is more restrictive.

Comment: Just to further add to the disappointment, the snippets plugin is commercial, and work has finally decided they're not willing to pay for it, so all the snippets we stored in there are lost.

Answer (score 13):

Good news, everyone!

Today I noticed that snippets are available on BitBucket:

https://bitbucket.org/snippets

Post about snippets in their blog: https://blog.bitbucket.org/2015/03/18/snippets-for-teams-are-here-with-a-rich-set-of-apis/