# how to create a hack stash

Tags: git, bitbucket

I'd like to have a place where I can quickly(effortless) add new projects and track their history. The projects are just random snippets of code or simple CRUDs where I could test different frameworks and keep them organized.

I'd like to be able on another computer to easily clone the whole stash of projects.

It'd look like:

```
hackstash
 - proj1
 - proj2
 - ...
 - projn
```

I'm considering to use git subrepo (from https://github.com/ingydotnet/git-subrepo#readme) and create the root project hackstash and host it under bitbucket.

But issue is, this feels a bit uneasy. I have to create a new project in bitbucket each time, add it to the hackstash, push that project and then also push hackstash.

Is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: Just had another idea(but not sure it's simplest): to never create a repo in bitbucket for proj1, ... projn. This would save lots of time creating all projects separately. But instead only create the hackstash repo. And inside proj1..projn, use git init but never push these to a repo. Don't know if this would work though.

Comment: or would git submodules/subtree work better for this? I found that subrepo is a bit unstable. I just don't want each proj1..projn to have a corresponding repo in bitbucket, if possible. Just want their history to evolve separately under hackstash repo.

Answer (score 2):

Considering those "random snippets of code or simple CRUDs" can evolve independently one from another, you might consider:

- [submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) indeed, but that means one Git repository per project, plus one global rpeository to reference the other ones.
- [GitHub Gists](https://help.github.com/en/github/writing-on-github/creating-gists), which you can clone back globally with [this script](https://gist.github.com/mbostock/3883098).
  If you need to be on [BitBucket instead, try snippets](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22101746/6309), which [has its own API](https://bitbucket.org/blog/snippets-for-teams-are-here-with-a-rich-set-of-apis).

The second option is lightweight, easier to maintain than full fledged repositories.

Comment: nice ideas thanks. One hurdle, gists seem not to allow folders. So not a very flexible option.

Comment: @zenlight No, but your question did not involved folders, only a collection of files under one hackstash project. And Gist can deliver on that. Each Gist can represent one project, with one or more files in it.

Comment: you're right, I didn't say. The end goal would be a place to store like spring, nodejs, react tutorials and samples. And be able to effortlessly create new ones with a simple command, like "hs c spring-tutorial-1"